# How do I set CMake on for Windows CLion?

Tags: wasm, cmake, boost, error

### Update:

Running:

- [Visuals Studios w/ Ubuntu Module](https://steemit.com/eos/@tokenika/installing-and-running-eos-on-windows)
- Windows (**Mac Answer Below**)
- CLion

I was able to figure out MinGW (probably not ideal solution if you want to use Git) / OpenSSL / Boost / WASM / Secp256k1 / GMP using Ubuntu in VS Windows:

```
-DCMAKE_SH="CMAKE_SH-NOTFOUND"
-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_random_numbers\LocalState\rootfs\usr\include\openssl
-DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_random_numbers\LocalState\rootfs\usr\include
-DBOOST_ROOT=C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_random_numbers\LocalState\rootfs\home\linux_user\opt\boost
-DWASM_ROOT=C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_random_numbers\LocalState\rootfs\home\linux_user\opt\wasm
-DSecp256k1_ROOT_DIR=C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_random_numbers\LocalState\rootfs\usr\local\include
-DSecp256k1_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_random_numbers\LocalState\rootfs\usr\local\include
-DSecp256k1_LIBRARY=C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_random_numbers\LocalState\rootfs\usr\local\lib
-DGMP_LIBRARIES=C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_random_numbers\LocalState\rootfs\usr\include\x86_64-linux-gnu\gnu
-DGMP_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_random_numbers\LocalState\rootfs\usr\include\x86_64-linux-gnu
```

---

Now I get this error for **OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR** / **OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY**:

```
Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY) (found
  version "1.0.2g")
```

Which I am struggling with because I cannot discern what it wants in the CMake Docs:

```
find_library(OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
    NAMES
      crypto
    NAMES_PER_DIR
    ${_OPENSSL_ROOT_HINTS_AND_PATHS}
    HINTS
      ${_OPENSSL_LIBDIR}
    PATH_SUFFIXES
      lib
  )
```

Maybe something like:

```
-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_random_numbers\LocalState\rootfs\usr\include\openssl
```

---

### Mac CMake:

```
-DWASM_ROOT=/home/user/ext/wasm-compiler/llvm/
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang
-DBOOST_ROOT=/home/user/opt/boost_1_67_0
-DBUILD_MONGO_DB_PLUGIN=true
-DBUILD_DOXYGEN=off
```

Comment: you've given so many great answers in this site! I wish I could help you on this one but I'm struggling with the same things right now! And I'm a well seasoned developer, but the C++ tooling, ecosystem, and the language itself, are just so cryptic and I don't have much experience with them.

Comment: It's a witch hunt for sure.  Each time I figure one out, a new one presents itself.  I'll keep kicking it until it gives me what I want.

Comment: Have you found a solution @Nat?

Comment: No, but this may help: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/blob/master/docs/guides/cmake.md